# Storing text of indefinite length, word by word, as it's being written

Tags: mysql, database, flat-file

I would like to write some plain text that is of indefinite length, and may eventually reach 10,000+ words. At any point others can see the progress of the text, page by page. The text need not be editable once it has been written.

Would I be better off storing each page (~100-200 words) in MySQL rows, or each page as a plain text file?

Comment: Why not just one huge `text` field for the whole document? What is your motivation of splitting the document into several pages in the database?

Comment: The text will be of indefinite length, retrieving 10,000 words each time from the database to only show 100 at a time would surely be inefficient no? Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: OK, I didn't get that from the question...

Answer (score 0):

Generally when storing 'files' the party line is to put the file on disk and store a link. Since you are talking about 100-200 words in each file I'd be inclined to just put them in a text field and store each 'page' as a row. This would give you the ability to view updates faster (faster than storing all 10K words at once). You'd have to store info about page order also just to keep things appearing correctly.